# Query using from / to tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one from / to table which has some data like this:

```
FROM                 | TO
---------------------+----------------
Apple iPhone SE 64GB | IPHONE SE 64GB
```

And I have two other tables which are populated with data from the FROM and from the TO columns respectively:

Table 1:

```
Device               | price 
---------------------+--------
Apple iPhone SE 64GB | xxxx
```

Table 2:

```
Device         | Price 
---------------+--------
IPHONE SE 64GB | XXXX
```

Sometimes, using a web scraper, the tables 1 and two get populated by values which won't exist in the From To table. For example:

Table 1:

```
Device         | price
---------------+--------
Samsung Flip Z | xxxx
```

Table 2:

```
Device                    | Price
--------------------------+--------
Smartphone Samsung Flip Z | XXXX
```

So, I'd have to insert one record inside the From To table like this:

```
FROM           | TO
---------------+----------------------------
Samsung Flip Z | Smartphone Samsung Flip Z
```

So, given these three tables, is it possible to have a query to find out which values are and which values are not in the From To Table? Because we have to fill it periodically.

Comment: add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Edited for more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use left join where don't match

```
  select t1.device 
  from table1 t1
  left join  table_from_to  tft on t1.device = tft.[from]
  where table tft.[from] is null
```

anyway FROM is reserved word so you should use square brackets better use another word

Comment: actually in SQL Server square brackets should be used [from]

Answer (score 0):

you can use "where not exists"

```
select *
FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id)
```